# a div element is not displaying as it should be because of floating on another elements

Tags: html, css

I have a blog where Im displaying the blog and the blog comments in the same div.

The comment is inside a div which is set to height:auto in the CSS. But the comment-div height is much more than the contents inside. Thats because a have a sidebar which is floating right.

Here is the code:

```css
#blog_section {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  max-width: 675px;
  margin: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#blog_section_topic {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  padding: 1%;
  color: grey;
}
#blog_section_topic h2 {
  margin: 1%;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: calibri;
}
#blog_section_info {
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: grey;
}
#blog_section_content {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
#blog_section_content img {
  margin: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
#blog_section_content p {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  line-height: 150%;
}
#blog_section_content div p a:link {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<aside id="sidebar_section" style='float:right;width:300px;height:1200px;background-color:pink;'>

  <div id="sidebar_recent_categories">
    <h2>
                Recent categories
            </h2> 

    <hr/>

    <div style="background-color:#999;margin-bottom:15px;padding:2px;border-radius:20px;">

      <p id="sidebar_recent_categories_category">
        <a style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;" href="#"> Testing </a>
      </p>

      <p id="date">Date: 14-07-2015 09:47:04</p>

    </div>

  </div>

</aside>

<div style='height:auto;padding-bottom:1px;' id="blog_section">

  <!-- title -->
  <div id="blog_section_topic">
    <h2>
                    Development            </h2>
  </div>

  <!-- info -->
  <div id="blog_section_info">

    <!-- date -->
    <p>Posted on 11-07-2015 05:39:20
      <!-- category name as a link -->
      in <a style="color:#f5f5f5;text-decoration:none;" href="category.php?id=4">PHP</a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <!-- contents -->
  <div id="blog_section_content">

    <!-- image -->
    <img src='upload_images/a08fe82b7d6image.jpg' style='max-width:500px;height:400px;float:initial;display:block;margin:auto;' />

    <div style="width:auto">
      <!-- text -->
      <div style="margin-bottom:20px;margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;display:block;height:auto;">

        <p style="margin-bottom:10px;">

          Web-developer '-_-'
        </p>
      </div>

      <!-- READ MORE -->
      <a href="blog.php?id=17"> <span style='color:#777;font-weight:bold;float:right;margin-right:20px;'> 
    
                          </span> 
      </a>

      <!-- edit & delete links -->
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li style="float:left;margin-right:20px;margin-left:20px;"><a class="edit_delete_buttons" href="delete_post.php?id=17&image=55a08fe82b7d6image.jpg">Delete this post</a>
          </li>

          <li><a class="edit_delete_buttons" href="edit_post.php?id=17">Edit this post</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- comment section -->
  <div id="comment_form" style='margin-bottom:2%; '>

    <!-- add a comment -->
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="add_comment.php" method="POST">

      <h1 style="font-size: 25px;font-weight: bold;color: #445668;margin-left:0px;margin-bottom:30px;text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #F2F2F2;">Add a Comment</h1>

      <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />
      <br/>
      <br/>

      <label for="name">Your Comment:</label>
      <br/>
      <textarea class="comment" name="comment" required></textarea>
      <br/>
      <br/>

      <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="17" />
      <input type="submit" value="Add comment" name="submit" />
    </form>

  </div>

  <!-- show comments -->

  <div style="margin:2%;background-color:#fff;padding:2%;height:auto;" class="show_comment">
    <!-- name of the poster -->
    Posted by: <span style="font-weight:bold;">User</span> on <span style='font-weight:bold;'>16-07-2015 16:03:56<a style='text-decoration:none;color:darkblue;float:right;' href='delete_comment.php?id=24'> Delete Comment </a> 
                             <!-- edit comment -->
                             <a style='text-decoration:none;color:darkblue;float:right;margin-right:10px;' href='edit_comment.php?id=24'> Edit Comment </a></span>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <!-- comment -->
    <div style="float:right;width:540px;height:auto;">
      Comment :)</div>

    <!-- image -->
    <div>
      <img src="profile_image/default.jpg" width="70px" style="margin-right:10px;">
    </div>

    <!-- float fix -->
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- float fix -->
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add overflow:hidden; to that div and it should work

```
#blog_section {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  max-width: 675px;
  margin: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#blog_section_topic {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  padding: 1%;
  color: grey;
}
#blog_section_topic h2 {
  margin: 1%;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: calibri;
}
#blog_section_info {
  margin: 1%;
  padding: 1%;
  background-color: grey;
}
#blog_section_content {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
#blog_section_content img {
  margin: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
#blog_section_content p {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  line-height: 150%;
}
#blog_section_content div p a:link {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<aside id="sidebar_section" style='float:right;width:300px;height:1200px;background-color:pink;'>

  <div id="sidebar_recent_categories">
    <h2>
                Recent categories
            </h2> 

    <hr/>

    <div style="background-color:#999;margin-bottom:15px;padding:2px;border-radius:20px;">

      <p id="sidebar_recent_categories_category">
        <a style="color:#fff;text-decoration:none;" href="#"> Testing </a>
      </p>

      <p id="date">Date: 14-07-2015 09:47:04</p>

    </div>

  </div>

</aside>

<div style='height:auto;padding-bottom:1px;' id="blog_section">

  <!-- title -->
  <div id="blog_section_topic">
    <h2>
                    Development            </h2>
  </div>

  <!-- info -->
  <div id="blog_section_info">

    <!-- date -->
    <p>Posted on 11-07-2015 05:39:20
      <!-- category name as a link -->
      in <a style="color:#f5f5f5;text-decoration:none;" href="category.php?id=4">PHP</a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <!-- contents -->
  <div id="blog_section_content">

    <!-- image -->
    <img src='upload_images/a08fe82b7d6image.jpg' style='max-width:500px;height:400px;float:initial;display:block;margin:auto;' />

    <div style="width:auto">
      <!-- text -->
      <div style="margin-bottom:20px;margin-left:20px;margin-right:20px;display:block;height:auto;">

        <p style="margin-bottom:10px;">

          Web-developer '-_-'
        </p>
      </div>

      <!-- READ MORE -->
      <a href="blog.php?id=17"> <span style='color:#777;font-weight:bold;float:right;margin-right:20px;'> 

                          </span> 
      </a>

      <!-- edit & delete links -->
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li style="float:left;margin-right:20px;margin-left:20px;"><a class="edit_delete_buttons" href="delete_post.php?id=17&image=55a08fe82b7d6image.jpg">Delete this post</a>
          </li>

          <li><a class="edit_delete_buttons" href="edit_post.php?id=17">Edit this post</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- comment section -->
  <div id="comment_form" style='margin-bottom:2%; '>

    <!-- add a comment -->
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="add_comment.php" method="POST">

      <h1 style="font-size: 25px;font-weight: bold;color: #445668;margin-left:0px;margin-bottom:30px;text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #F2F2F2;">Add a Comment</h1>

      <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" required />
      <br/>
      <br/>

      <label for="name">Your Comment:</label>
      <br/>
      <textarea class="comment" name="comment" required></textarea>
      <br/>
      <br/>

      <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="17" />
      <input type="submit" value="Add comment" name="submit" />
    </form>

  </div>

  <!-- show comments -->

  <div style="margin:2%;background-color:#fff;padding:2%;height:auto;overflow:hidden;" class="show_comment">
    <!-- name of the poster -->
    Posted by: <span style="font-weight:bold;">User</span> on <span style='font-weight:bold;'>16-07-2015 16:03:56<a style='text-decoration:none;color:darkblue;float:right;' href='delete_comment.php?id=24'> Delete Comment </a> 
                             <!-- edit comment -->
                             <a style='text-decoration:none;color:darkblue;float:right;margin-right:10px;' href='edit_comment.php?id=24'> Edit Comment </a></span>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <!-- comment -->
    <div style="float:right;width:540px;height:auto;">
      Comment :)</div>

    <!-- image -->
    <div>
      <img src="profile_image/default.jpg" width="70px" style="margin-right:10px;">
    </div>

    <!-- float fix -->
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- float fix -->
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Happy to help someone.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to change.

- Firstly, remove the clearfix divs, this method is messy and obsolete at this stage
- I would then have a parent wrapper containing the blog and sidebar divs. You can then clearfix the wrapper using CSS, see the code below
- I would remove the fixed height on the sidebar - if you want full height columns search on Stack Overflow for solutions, this is well documented

**Clearfix CSS:**

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```